# CS50 runoff: voting algorithm to tabulate the voting preferences of voters in a runoff election

Tags: c, arrays, cs50

I'd really appreciate a fresh pair of eyes to spot my mistake! Preferences is a two dimensional array (voter versus preference) containing the numbers of the candidates that each voter has selected in order of rank (e.g. preference[0][0] = i indicates that i is the 0th voter's first preference candidate). I have't included a loop for rank because this only increases if the candidate has been eliminated and it should revert to 0 every time a new voter is considered.

I've worked on this problem for quite some time but I'm still getting some errors in check50 for tabulate and print_winner. For tabulate there is only a problem in cases where one candidate has been eliminated.

```
void tabulate(void)
{
    // Set rank to equal zero first. 
    // This will only change if the voter's first preference is eliminated.       
    int rank = 0; 
    // Loop through voters.             
    for (int voter = 0; voter < voter_count; voter++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)// Loop through candidate possibilities
        { 
        // When candidate has been identified and is not eliminated execute this statement.                 
            if (preferences[voter][rank] == i && candidates[i].eliminated == false) 
            {
                candidates[i].votes += 1;
                rank = 0;
                // Rank is reset to zero as this may have been increased in the else if statement.
            }
            else if (preferences[voter][rank] == i && candidates[i].eliminated == true) 
            {
                // If the candidate has been eliminated the rank is increased.                    
                rank += 1; 
                voter -= 1;
                // The voter is decreased so on returning to the 'for' loop the same voter is checked again. 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "getting some errors".

Comment: :) tabulate counts votes when all candidates remain in election.

:) tabulate counts votes when one candidate is eliminated.

:( tabulate counts votes when multiple candidates are eliminated.

So the code I've written works unless more than one candidate has been eliminated from the election...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `voter -= 1;` is bad. Program is still in the `i` loop, so expect the unexpected because program may try to look at `preferences[-1][1]`.

Here's an election where the function will fail: 4 candidates a b c d; 5 voters

```
voter| votes
1    | b c a d  
2    | a d b c  
3    | a d b c  
4    | d a c b
5    | d a c b
```

"b" and "c" will get eliminated. In tabulate, candidate "a" should get a vote from voter 1. But will they? Since function is looping through the candidates, no. When it processes candidate "a", it is neither rank 0 nor eliminated; it doesn't get a vote. And it will not be processed again. Based on that, I think the program needs to loop through ranks instead of candidates. As soon as a vote is tallied, end that loop.

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out!! When I add a break statement after voter -=1; it solves the problem! I tried it another way, looping through the rank as you suggest, and I couldn't get it to work... I'm sure there's a more concise way of doing things but I'm glad this worked finally anyway :):)